# Problems with BLE throughput Degradation on Android 12

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-galaxy, samsung

I'm developing an Android app that receives approximately 117 kbps of ble data per second.

There was no problem with versions earlier than Android 12, but the update to version 12 caused an average of 85 kbps of data to be received.

How can I solve this problem?

```java
manager.connect(mRemoteDevice)
//                        .usePreferredPhy(PhyRequest.PHY_LE_1M_MASK | PhyRequest.PHY_LE_2M_MASK)
.usePreferredPhy(PhyRequest.PHY_LE_2M_MASK)
.done(device -> {
    mConnected = true;
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.updateDeviceStatus(mPosition, BluetoothScanResponseModel.DeviceStatusMode.DEVICE_SEARCHING_SERVICE_MODE);
                            manager.enableFluxCapacitor();
                        })
    .fail(((device, status) -> {
                            
                        }))
                        .enqueue();
```

Tablet Environment: Galaxy S6 Lite

Comment: I don't think Android 12 has any fundamental changes. Try debugging this systematically. What is the MTU you are getting? Are you really getting a phy_2m connection or just a 1m connection? ...and comparing with other phones that have the higher speed

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie The app I provide specifies the minimum specifications. I think the Galaxy Tab S6 is a device that is perfect in terms of specifications.
MTU request is 512. I don't see any fundamental changes in Android, but I think it's a problem with Samsung Tablet.
The bottom line is that all devices before 11 are functioning normally, and only 12 versions of the device that performed OS updates are problematic.